# How can I have a per project Live Template for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, live-templates

So Android Studio have access to live templates, I wanted to tailor the logi/logw/etc. live templates to better suit the project

Namely, I want to change them to a project specific Log class that say only show log in debug build, or to log errors to both console and to an external logging service?

So in one project it could be

com.test.util.Log

in another project it could be

com.test2.logger.Log

and I want to load each for each different project when they launch.

Comment: Android Studio - Live Templates in Action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7L53tdusak4

Comment: I don't think this allows me to lock down each specific change / template to a project. It shows the creation of them yes, but not to lock it down to one project / have per project settings.